# MSTest, Targeting multiple Framework version

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, version, mstest

We use TFS (2010) for Continuous Integration. Solution Contains .NET 4 ,and Silverlight 4 projects. Everything was working fine, until one day MSTest.exe stopped running UnitTest dlls, with this message : 
***A test run can only be targeted to single .Net framework version. Targeting multiple Framework version in single run is unsupported.***

***What I did:***
I have checked to see if there has been any config changes in the solution, but discovered none. files with .Testsettings and .vsdmi are intact.

Also we have three branches on TFS, which use same controller and Agent. and all the builds have stopped working. 
I tried running MSTest from command-line, and same problem. seems if there are SL and .NET test dlls, MSTest does not work.

**The complete log for MSTest is here :**

Run MSTest for TestAssemblies

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testSettings:"C:\Builds\1\Product\Sources\OM\build.testsettings" /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\1\Product\Binaries" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\1\Product\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\1\Product\Binaries\OM.Views.Tests.dll" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\1\Product\Binaries\OM.ApplicationServices.UnitTests.dll" /publish:"http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/3750" /teamproject:"Products" /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"Release" 
Loading C:\Builds\1\Product\Sources\OM\build.testsettings...
Loading C:\Builds\1\Product\Binaries\OM.ApplicationServices.UnitTests.dll...
Loading C:\Builds\1\Product\Binaries\OM.ViewModels.Tests.dll...
Starting execution...
A test run can only be targeted to single .Net framework version. Targeting multiple Framework version in single run is unsupported.
There are no results to be published.
```

Comment: Running Silverlight and .net framework tests separately, now. Could not figure out why it happened.